# SwiftUI - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: layout, swiftui, constraints, uinavigationbar

I am really new to SwiftUI. Did many lessons of the course of Angela. I checked the problem with the same error message but I have the feeling that these threads are related to SWIFT and not to SwiftUI. I don't understand which constraint I should skip when using only VStack or NavigationView...

I want to switch from a general view (my starting view) via some buttons to different areas of the app.

Start-View:

- Button 1

  - Member-View (List View)

    - Member View Details
- Button 2

  - Club View (List View)

    - Club Details

My code is reduced to the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct StartMenueView: View {
    @State private var selection: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail View"), tag: "A", selection: $selection) { EmptyView() }
                
                HStack {
                    Button("Detail View") {
                        selection = "A"
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Master")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the error message which appears when running the app.

```
2022-02-09 19:35:42.884859+0100 SwiftUIByExample[20911:419354] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd4640 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f151e0'Master']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd4690 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x156f151e0'Master'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd5360 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd53b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fcf200 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003ff7250 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fcf0c0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd4640 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f151e0'Master']   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-02-09 19:35:42.885452+0100 SwiftUIByExample[20911:419354] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd8780 UIView:0x156e0f510.trailing == _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x156e0edb0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd4c30 'Mask_Trailing_Trailing' _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x156e0edb0.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd4d70 'MaskEV_Leading_BIB_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750]-(0)-[UIView:0x156e0f510]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd5360 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd53b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fcf200 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003ff7250 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fcf0c0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd8780 UIView:0x156e0f510.trailing == _UIBackButtonMaskView:0x156e0edb0.trailing   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2022-02-09 19:35:42.889483+0100 SwiftUIByExample[20911:419354] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd45f0 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd5360 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd53b0 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00]-(6)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fcf200 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1260'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003ff7250 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fcf0c0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(8)-[UILayoutGuide:0x6000025e1500'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x156f13970 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003fd45f0 'BIB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x156f17750]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x156f14e00 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: In general, if it's SwiftUI itself generating these warnings, I'd say they are relatively safe to ignore unless you're seeing unexpected behavior.

Comment: I have added 
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
to the NavigationView at the end of the closure and the warnings disappeared. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to NavigationView will solve the issue.

```
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```

Source:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/100-days-of-swiftui/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-warning-when-adding-a-navigation-title/12883.